# hbm2ddl.auto update and new boolean property added to an existing table with records

Tags: jpa-2.0, hbm2ddl

I have a mapped entity with JPA in a PostgreSQL database.

The table exists and I have some records in it, now I want to add a simple new boolean (not **B**oolean) property.

In logs I can correctly see the alter table using not null because I chose boolean and not Boolean, it is all right but....
without seeing any errors, the database isn't being updated.

Trying to execute the alter table directly in my SQL client finally I can see the problem, that is the column that I'm just adding contains null values...
Obviously already existent records will have null values as soon as that column will be created.

That said, what could I do if I want to create a not null property in a table having already at least one record?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood from your question, you are getting issues with your earlier added table rows when you update your table by adding a new `boolean` column.

Your previous table rows gets `null` values for the newly added column.

You can set the default values on your `JPA` entity properties using `columnDefinition` provided as an attribute in `@Column` annotation.

If you want to add a new boolean property in your `JPA` entity you can try this

```
@Column(name = "is_active", columnDefinition="tinyint(1) default 1")
private boolean isActive;
```

And since you are using `hbm2ddl`, this will not only create a fresh `boolean` column for you but also give it a default of `true`. It will also set true for all the previously added rows in that table.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks but your solution is not dbms independent, for example in PostgreSQL tinyint is not a valid type and I should write ...bool default true;